How to stop Windows file transfer consuming all network bandwidth
When I initiate any file transfer from my laptop, over WIFI, to my network drive, immediately all other network traffic is interrupted until the file transfer is complete.
For example, if I am watching a video and initiate a file transfer in the background the video stops and remains in "buffering" unless I halt the file transfer.  Windows clearly is deciding to prioritise file transfer tasks, and to do so in such an extreme way that it apportions upwards of 99% of available bandwidth to that one task preventing anything else from being usable.  Even navigating network locations becomes extremely laggy.
How can Windows be told to balance the priority?  Or even how can a manual limit to the bandwidth allocated to file transfer tasks be set?
EDIT: Adding more info that it appears may be relevant.

File transfer is to/from a NAS.
The problem is with any other task that requires access to the NAS, browsing, opening files, playing videos etc.. None of these can be done while the file transfer is active, or they happen extremely slowly as if they are being assigned virtually no bandwidth.
Internet access and browsing speed remain the same with no performance issues.  Similarly accessing anything on my laptop's local directories is unaffected.

